# How to replace an existing image instead of adding additional images?

Tags: python, tkinter

This is my first time here, and I would really appreciate some help with this.

So I have some code which runs a Tkinter tab and shows 2 buttons. If you click the first one, a picture of a cat appears.

However, if you click the button again, the same picture appears again at the bottom, making there 2.

If I click the other button, titled N/A, a different picture appears. But if you click the button again, the picture duplicates.

I want to make it so that when each button is pressed, the image is replaced, not duplicated.

Here is what I have so far.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

class HomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        self.WelcomeLabel = Label(root, text="Welcome to the game!",
                                  bg="Black", fg="White")
        self.WelcomeLabel.pack(fill=X)

        self.FirstButton = Button(root, text="Start", bg="RED", fg="White",
                                 command=self.FirstClick)
        self.FirstButton.pack(side=LEFT, fill=X)

        self.SecondButton = Button(root, text="N/A", bg="Blue", fg="White",
                                   command=self.SecondClick)
        self.SecondButton.pack(side=LEFT, fill=X)

    def FirstClick(self):
        FirstPhoto = PhotoImage(file="keyboardcat.gif")
        FiLabel = Label(root, image=FirstPhoto)
        FiLabel.img = FirstPhoto
        FiLabel.pack()


    def SecondClick(self):
        FirstPhoto = PhotoImage(file="donald.gif")
        FiLabel = Label(root, image=FirstPhoto)
        FiLabel.img = FirstPhoto
        FiLabel.pack()


k = HomeClass(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

That's becouse every time you click a button, you're calling FirstClick method which in turn creates new instance of PhotoImage class. I think it would be better to store FirstPhoto and in every FirstClick method call check if it is already has value or not.

```
class HomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        self.WelcomeLabel = Label(root, text="Welcome to the game!",
                              bg="Black", fg="White")
        self.WelcomeLabel.pack(fill=X)

        self.FirstButton = Button(root, text="Start", bg="RED", fg="White",
                             command=self.FirstClick)
        self.FirstButton.pack(side=LEFT, fill=X)

        self.SecondButton = Button(root, text="N/A", bg="Blue", fg="White",
                               command=self.SecondClick)
        self.SecondButton.pack(side=LEFT, fill=X)

        self.FirstPhoto = None

    def FirstClick(self):
        if self.FirstPhoto is None:
            self.FirstPhoto = PhotoImage(file="ksiazka.png")
            self.FiLabel = Label(root, image=self.FirstPhoto)
            self.FiLabel.img = self.FirstPhoto
            self.FiLabel.pack()
```

Comment: Thanks! I made the changes and the picture no longer duplicates!

Comment: However, I am unsure of how you would go about making it so that when the N/A button is pressed, the image on the screen changes to a different one. Do you have any ideas how that would work? TIA :)

Comment: Ok, could you give me an example of how this would look? I'm still getting to grips with all of this,

Answer (score 0):

In this example you have two methods FirstClick, SecondClick to display an image and two methods to clear an first and second image accordingly: clearFirstImage, clearSecondImage. You just have to add two buttons to trigger those clear methods :)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename

root = Tk()

class HomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = Frame(master)


        self.WelcomeLabel = Label(root, text="Welcome to the game!",
                                bg="Black", fg="White")
        self.WelcomeLabel.pack(fill=X)

        self.FirstButton = Button(root, text="Start", bg="RED", fg="White",
                                command=self.FirstClick)
        self.FirstButton.pack(side=LEFT, fill=X)

        self.SecondButton = Button(root, text="N/A", bg="Blue", fg="White",
                                command=self.SecondClick)
        self.SecondButton.pack(side=LEFT, fill=X)

        self.ToggleButtonText = "Show image"
        self.ToggleButton = Button(root, text=self.ToggleButtonText, bg="Grey", fg="White",
                                command=self.ToggleClick)
        self.ToggleButton.pack(side=LEFT, fill=X)

        self.FirstPhoto = None
        self.FiLabel = None

        self.SecondPhoto = None
        self.SecondPhotoLabel = None

        self.ToggleButtonPhoto = None
        self.ToggleButtonPhotoLabel = None
        self.frame.pack()

    def FirstClick(self):
        if self.FirstPhoto is None:
            self.FirstPhoto = PhotoImage(file="ksiazka.png")
            self.FiLabel = Label(root, image=self.FirstPhoto)
            self.FiLabel.img = self.FirstPhoto
            self.FiLabel.pack()

    def ToggleClick(self):
        if self.ToggleButtonPhoto is None:
            self.ToggleButtonPhoto = PhotoImage(file="ksiazka.png")
            self.ToggleButtonPhotoLabel = Label(self.frame, image=self.ToggleButtonPhoto)
            self.ToggleButtonPhotoLabel.img = self.ToggleButtonPhoto
            self.ToggleButtonPhotoLabel.pack()

            # and set label
            self.ToggleButton.config(text="Hide image")
        else:
            self.ToggleButton.config(text="Show image")
            self.ToggleButtonPhotoLabel.destroy()
            self.ToggleButtonPhotoLabel.img = None
            self.ToggleButtonPhotoLabel = None
            self.ToggleButtonPhoto = None
            self.frame.pack()


    def SecondClick(self):
        filename = askopenfilename()
        allowed_extensions = ['jpg', 'png']
        if len(filename) > 0 and filename.split('.')[-1] in allowed_extensions:
            self.SecondPhoto = PhotoImage(file=filename)
            self.SecondPhotoLabel = Label(root, image=self.SecondPhoto)
            self.SecondPhotoLabel.img = self.SecondPhoto
            self.SecondPhotoLabel.pack()

    def clearFirstImage(self):
        self.FirstPhoto = None
        self.FiLabel = None

    def clearSecondImage(self):
        self.SecondPhoto = None
        self.SecondPhotoLabel = None


k = HomeClass(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't seem to work; the second image no longer shows. I'm trying to make it so that the buttons toggle between the different images. Do you have any ideas about how I might go about doing that?

Comment: Ok, i've added corrected version, now you have a toggle button which shows an image if there is None or destroys it if there is one, note that button text also changes. SecondClick button now shows file select menu and if selected file has allowed extension then displays it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to change SecondPhoto

```
def SecondClick(self):
    if self.SecondPhoto is None:
            self.SecondPhoto = PhotoImage(file="ksiazka.png")
            self.SecondPhotoLabel = Label(root, image=self.FirstPhoto)
            self.SecondPhotoLabel.img = self.SecondPhoto
            self.SecondPhotoLabel.pack()

     Else:
          self.SecondPhotoLabel.config(image='newimage')
          self.SecondPhotoLabel.update()
```

Note - you can declare the newImage before as you have to read it with PhotoImage and then just put the image name in the .config

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace an existing image, first create the `label` the image is displayed in, and simply reconfigure only its image option with each click. Below is an example that does that:

```
try:                        # In order to be able to import tkinter for
    import tkinter as tk    # either in python 2 or in python 3
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk


def download_images():
    # In order to fetch the image online
    try:
        import urllib.request as url
    except ImportError:
        import urllib as url
    url.urlretrieve("https://i.stack.imgur.com/57uJJ.gif", "13.gif")
    url.urlretrieve("https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LThi.gif", "8.gif")


class ImageFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)
        self._create_widgets()
        self._display_widgets()


    def _create_widgets(self):
        def __create_image_label():
            def ___load_images():
                self.label.images = list()
                self.label.images.append(tk.PhotoImage(file="8.gif"))
                self.label.images.append(tk.PhotoImage(file="13.gif"))


            self.label = tk.Label(self)
            ___load_images()


        def __create_buttons():
            self.buttons = list()
            for i in range(2):
                self.buttons.append(tk.Button(self, text=i,
                                command=lambda i=i: self.replace_image(i)))

        __create_image_label()
        __create_buttons()


    def replace_image(self, button_index):
        """
        Replaces the image in label attribute based on the index of the
        button pressed.
        """
        self.label['image'] = self.label.images[button_index]


    def _display_widgets(self):
        self.label.pack()
        for i in range(2):
            self.buttons[i].pack(fill='x', expand=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #download_images() # comment out after initial run
    root = tk.Tk()
    frame = ImageFrame(root)
    frame.pack()
    tk.mainloop()
```